# Trying to create a Loop that moves Rows to a different sheet based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to make a loop that checks for the string (defined by the user) in all the cells in column "A" and cuts every row where cell "A" doesn't contain the string and moves it to another sheet (Cml) I have the following code that runs without any error message but it doesn't seem to do what it's supposed to.

```
Sub PSFormat()
    Dim cb As Shape
    Dim Cml As Worksheet
    Dim Aud As Worksheet
    Dim z As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim myDate2 As String

    Set Aud = Worksheets("CURRENT")
    Set Cml = Worksheets("OLD")


    myDate2 = InputBox("Please enter the date you are reviewing in yyyy-mm-dd format")

    With Aud
        LastRow = Aud.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row with data in column "A"
        For z = 2 To LastRow
            If InStr(Aud.Range("A" & z).Value2, myDate2) < 0 Then ' check if current cell in column "A" contains "myDate2" defined by the user

            'if the cell in col "A" doesn't contain "myDate2" then cut the entire row and paste it to sheet Cml
                Aud.Rows((1) & z).EntireRow.Cut _
                Destination:=Cml.Rows((1) & z)
            End If
        Next z
    End With

    End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[UPDATE] This is the entire macro for reference.

```
Sub PSFormat()
Dim cb As Shape
Dim Cml As Worksheet
Dim Aud As Worksheet
Dim z As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim myDate2 As String

Set Aud = Worksheets("CURRENT")
Set Cml = Worksheets("OLD")


myDate2 = InputBox("Please enter the date you are reviewing in yyyy-mm-dd format")

Aud.Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert

        Aud.Range("A1").Value = "TIME"
        Aud.Range("B1").Value = "ACTION"
        Aud.Range("C1").Value = "PLATFORM"
        Aud.Range("D1").Value = "MAKER ID"
        Aud.Range("E1").Value = "APPLICATION"
        Aud.Range("F1").Value = "JUSTIFICATION"

        Aud.Range("A1:F1").AutoFilter

LastRow = Aud.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 1 To LastRow

                If Aud.Range("D" & x).Value <> "PSECSELF" Then Aud.Range("F" & x).Value = "A"
                If Aud.Range("D" & x).Value = "PSECSELF" Then Aud.Range("F" & x).Value = "N/A"
                If Aud.Range("B" & x).Value = "Unsuccessful login attempt" Then Aud.Range("F" & x) = "N/A"
                If Aud.Range("B" & x).Value = "Administrator login" Then Aud.Range("F" & x) = "N/A"
                If Aud.Range("B" & x).Value = "Remote help successful" Then Aud.Range("F" & x) = "N/A"
                If Aud.Range("B" & x).Value = "Helpdesk user deleted" Then Aud.Range("F" & x) = "N/A"
                If Aud.Range("B" & x).Value = "Token deleted" Then Aud.Range("F" & x) = "N/A"

Next x


With Aud
    LastRow = Aud.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row with data in column "A"
    For z = 2 To LastRow
        If InStr(Aud.Range("A" & z).Value2, myDate2) < 0 Then ' check if current cell in column "A" contains "myDate2" defined by the user

        'if the cell in col "A" doesn't contain "myDate2" then cut the entire row and paste it to sheet Cml
            Aud.Range("A" & z).EntireRow.Cut _
            Destination:=Cml.Rows((1) & z)
        End If
    Next z
End With

  Aud.Range("F1").Value = "JUSTIFICATION"
  Aud.Range("F2").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="A"

     Aud.Buttons.Add(617.25, 24, 72, 72).Select
        Selection.OnAction = "PSSaveFile"
            Selection.Characters.Text = "SAVE"

    Aud.Range("F2").Select


MsgBox "Please filter for yesterday's date first!"

End Sub
```

Comment: What is it doing?

Comment: Why are you using source and destination rows of 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 110, 111, 112, ... 120, 121, ... 199, 1100, 1101, etc?

Comment: As YowE3K said. Also, is there a reason why you can't use Union to collect the rows to remove, and then paste in one go? What happens to the empty rows left behind by your cut? Currently i think you line should be  Aud.Range("A" & z).EntireRow.Cut to remove the rows.

Comment: I tried `Aud.Range("A" & z).EntireRow.Cut` and it still doesn't do it. I mean the rows aren't even getting cut when I run the code. @YowE3K What do you mean? I didn't specify any source/destination based on row numbers. @QHarr it doesn't do anything :D the script just runs without doing anything at all

Comment: That is because this needs to change from <0 to this   If InStr(Aud.Range("A" & z).Value2, myDate2) =0

Comment: If `z` is `2` then `(1) & z` is `"12"`, so you will be cutting row 12 and copying it to row 12.  If `z` is `19` then `(1) & z` is `"119"`, so you will be cutting row 119 and copying it to row 119.

Comment: Ah okay, I don't want to do that. Examined rows start from A2 till the last row with data. So my syntax with (1)&z is wrong. What would work in it's place then?

Comment: Well `Aud.Rows((1) & z).EntireRow.Cut` should probably just be `Aud.Rows(z).Cut` (a `Row` is already an entire row, so you don't need the `EntireRow` part), but I don't often use `Cut` so I'm not sure whether that will actually delete the row from the source sheet at the same time as it copies to the destination or whether it just clears the row.  (If it does delete the row, you will need to change your loop to go from `LastRow To 2 Step -1`.)

Comment: I made your adjustments the code runs but nothing happens whatsoever...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the following but as noted in comments, you are leaving a gap in the range where you cut from. In which case, deleting the empty rows afterwards is a good idea. Assumes values in the sheet are formatted as strings.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PSFormat()
    Dim cb As Shape
    Dim Cml As Worksheet
    Dim Aud As Worksheet
    Dim z As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim myDate2 As String
    Dim LastRowOld As Long
    Dim cutRange As Range

    Set Aud = Worksheets("CURRENT")
    Set Cml = Worksheets("OLD")

    myDate2 = InputBox("Please enter the date you are reviewing in yyyy-mm-dd format")

    With Aud

        LastRow = Aud.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row with data in column "A"
        LastRowOld = Cml.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For z = 2 To LastRow

             If Not IsEmpty(Aud.Range("A" & z)) And InStr(Aud.Range("A" & z).Value2, myDate2) =0 Then  Then ' check if current cell in column "A" contains "myDate2" defined by the user
                If Not cutRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set cutRange = Union(cutRange, Aud.Range("A" & z))
                Else
                    Set cutRange = Aud.Range("A" & z)
                End If

                'if the cell in col "A" doesn't contain "myDate2" then cut the entire row and paste it to sheet Cml
            End If
        Next z
    End With

    If Not cutRange Is Nothing Then
       cutRange.Copy Cml.Cells(LastRowOld, "A")
       cutRange.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: oopsy my bad in this case. Edited. Thanks YowE3K.

Comment: Hello I tested the code and I get the error: "Error 1004: This can't be done on the entire selection, Select a single range and try again" when debugging it takes me to the following line: `cutRange.EntireRow.Cut Cml.Cells(LastRowOld + 1 , "A")`

Comment: I removed "Option Explicit" as it wants to force me to declare all the "x" definitions in the rest of my code, but I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: This happens if there are blank cells in the range

Comment: Just double-checked there are no blank cells, there's a header inserted to A1 and from A2 down all the cells are filled.

Comment: What happens if you change the last couple of lines to 
    cutRange.Copy Cml.Cells(LastRowOld, "A")
    cutRange.Delete

Comment: "expected end of statement"

Comment: Should be one two lines . cutRange.Delete being on a new line, perhaps i should have put as  cutRange.Copy Cml.Cells(LastRowOld, "A"):  cutRange.Delete       In this case : means new statement

Comment: ah got it, unfortunately I get the "Object variable not set" error now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160272/discussion-between-qharr-and-rhyfelwr).

Comment: I misidentified the cell contents, they were Dates and not Strings so the code you provided worked the entire time (probably my original code too haha) Thank you so much for your time and your help!